# Distribution convergence of $n\Big(\log(n)\Big) X_{\min} /X_{\max}$

Tags: probability, convergence, slutsky-theorem

I'm figuring out the **asymptotic distribution** of the following.

$$
n\Big(\log(n)\Big) X_{\min} /X_{\max}
$$

where $X_1, \cdots, X_n \overset{iid}{\sim} \operatorname{Exp}(1)$

I know it **converges in distribution** to $\operatorname{Exp}(1)$. But it's hard for me to prove it.

I **tried** :

I tried using **Slutsky**'s theorem, with $n X_{\min} \overset{d}{\to} \operatorname{Exp}(1)$ and $X_{\max} / \log(n) \overset{p}{\to} 1$.

Since $n X_{min}  \sim Exp(1)$ we have $nX_{\min} \overset{d}{\to} \operatorname{Exp}(1)$ and $P\Big(X_{\max} / \log(n) \le y \Big) = \Big(1 - (\frac{1}{n})^y \Big)^n$.

We have $X_{\max} / \log(n) \overset{p}{\to} 1$ only when $y > 1$. Otherwise it converges to 0 (when $0 <y < 1$) or $1/e$ (when $y = 1$).

Comment: I skimmed your proposed solution and didn't see a gap (only bad wording in the penultimate sentence but it's clear what you mean :)) - where are you actually stuck?

Comment: @P.Windridge Oh, to say $n\Big( log(n) \Big) X_{min}/X_{max}$ converges in distribution $Exp(1)$, I need to show probability convergence for any $x > 0$ (support)

Comment: Perhaps (speculation) show $\mathbb{E}X_{max}/\log n \rightarrow 1$ and $\sigma(X_{max})/\log n \rightarrow 0$ and use Chebyshev?

Comment: moreblue, not sure what you mean by "for any $x > 0$" but you seem to have correctly written down the distribution function for $X_{max}/log(n)$ from which you can see the latter converges to 1 in probability (although it's not clearly articulated :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's clear this up.  You basically have the answer.  You already observed that $n X_{min} \sim Exp(1)$.  This follows from the fact that for any $t > 0$ we have

$$
\mathbb{P}(n X_{min} > t ) = \mathbb{P}(X_i > t/n,\; i=1,2,\ldots,n) = \mathbb{P}(X_i > t/n)^n = (e^{-t/n})^n = e^{-t}.
$$

Thus, trivially $n X_{min}\to Exp(1)$.

Similarly, as you mention, for any $y > 0$,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{max}/\ln(n) < y) = \left(1 - e^{-y \ln(n)}\right)^n
=\left(1 - n^{-y}\right)^n.
$$

At this point you need a little analysis for the right hand side, which you seem to have done.  It is more transparent to see after taking logs and using the fact that $\ln(1 + x) = x + o(x)$ as $x \to 0$ (e.g. Taylor's Theorem). In fact $-2x \le \ln(1 - x) \le -x$ for small enough $x$.

If $y<1$ then 
$$
\ln\mathbb{P}(X_{max}/\ln(n) < y) = n \ln (1 - n^{-y}) \le -n^{1-y} \to -\infty,
$$
from which it follows that $\mathbb{P}(X_{max}/\ln(n) < y) \to 0$.

If $y > 1$ then eventually (i.e. for $n$ large enough)
$$
\ln\mathbb{P}(X_{max}/\ln(n) < y) = n \ln (1 - n^{-y}) \ge -2 n^{1-y} \to 0,
$$
and so $\mathbb{P}(X_{max}/\ln(n) < y) \to 1$.

Thus, for any $\epsilon > 0$,
$$
\mathbb{P}(1 - \epsilon < X_{max}/\ln(n) < 1 + \epsilon)
 = \mathbb{P}(X_{max}/\ln(n) < 1 + \epsilon)
 - \mathbb{P}(X_{max}/\ln(n) \le 1 - \epsilon)
\to 1,
$$
which is the definition of $X_{max}/\ln(n) \to 1$ in probability.

Finally apply [Slutsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem).